# RxJs: $q.when analog in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, rxjs

In AngularJS 1.* I used to write this part of code, to refresh auth-token:

```
...

if (!refreshTokenInProgress) {
  refreshTokenInProgress = AuthService.refreshToken();
}


$q.when(refreshTokenInProgress, function () {
  refreshTokenInProgress = null;

  // re-send requests with error
  ...
}, function () {
  // logout if refresh token rejected

  refreshTokenInProgress = null;

  ...
});

...
```

How can I translate this code with Observable in Angular 2?

I even have no idea, because this won't work:

```
if (!refreshTokenInProgress) {
  refreshTokenInProgress = AuthService.refreshToken().subscribe();
}

Observable.forkJoin([this.refreshTokenInProgress]).subscribe(
  success => this.refreshTokenInProgress = null
);
```

What is the equal for `$q.when` in RxJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable.of(data) is analog of $q.when

You can read my post on mapping $q to RxJS at [$Q map to RxJS](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova)

here is an example from real code:

```
spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of([{id: 1}, {id: 2}]));
```

or little bit more complex one:

```
   deleteRole(role: Role) {
Observable.fromPromise(this.confirmDialogService.open(DELETE_ROLE_TITLE, DELETE_ROLE_CONFIRM_BODY({name: role.name})))
  .switchMap(result => result ? Observable.of(result) : Observable.empty())
  .switchMap(() => this.rolesService.getUsersForRole(role.id))
  .switchMap(({elements: users}) => {
    return _.isEmpty(users) ?
      Observable.of(users) :
      Observable.fromPromise(
        this.confirmDialogService.open(ROLE_IN_USE_TITLE,
          ROLE_IN_USE_CONFIRM_BODY({users: users.map(({firstName, lastName}) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`)}),
          {hideCancelButton: true})
      ).switchMap(() => Observable.empty());
  })
  .switchMap(() => this.rolesService.deleteRole(role))
  .subscribe(data => {
      this.toastr.success(`Role '${role.name}' is deleted`, 'Success');
      this.findallRoles(); //Refresh role grid;
      this.roleDeleted.emit();
    },
    error => {
      this.toastr.error(error, 'Error (rolesService.delete)!', {dismiss: 'click'});
      console.error(error);
    });
```

}

Comment: `if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
          this.refreshTokenInProgress = authService.refreshToken().subscribe();
        }

        Observable.of(this.refreshTokenInProgress).subscribe(
          result => console.log('res')
        );`

this isn't working correctly

writing `Observable.of(this.refreshTokenInProgress).toPromise().then(function () {` isn't a good idea :)

Comment: omg :) i switched to use `ngx-restangular` and everything is fine :)